# A way to accept more than one answer would be useful

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

More often than not, I get more than one really good answer to a particular question that I have posted.

There is no way one can **appreciate** that more than by up-voting both answers, because we are only allowed to accept one answer, and I have already accepted another answer.

A way to accept more than one answer would be useful.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: @Rich: No need to be caustic. Aeon is new, and doesn't have the historical-knowledge that others do here. Some questions may be re-asked for time to time. Just be courteous, and point them to their answers.

Comment: Yeah, some matters need to be resolved don't they, or do we rather shove it under the carpet.

Comment: Don't argue about it, just close it already.

Comment: @Aeon: Don't let some of the responses here affect you negatively. Most of us are genuinely interested in helping educate others in a respectful manner. Just flag any comments that you feel are unnecessarily-rude and the proper actions will be taken.

Comment: @Jonathan,No negativity here! It's just that I wont offer by right cheek if someone hits my left.

Comment: @Jonathan, After all I'm here for the interest of the community not to have a mutual slugfest.

Comment: @Aeon: Glad to have you aboard! Keep the ideas coming.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/add-assisted-answer-feature-to-questions
And: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, this is definitely a topic that has had its fair share of air-time. I saw one of those when searching for dupes as well, but decided to go with the first result you posted.

Comment: *decided to answer a dupe again anyway for the rep.

Comment: Flagged and requested a merge; shame to see the discussion split up this much.

Comment: @Rich I've been capped for hours, actually. Answered because the OP asked. If an answer exists in more than one spot, it's easier to find.

Comment: @Shog9: Agreed. What a mess.

Comment: @Shog9: Merge sounds like a good idea.

Comment: *as long as I get accepted beforehand.

Comment: @Rich: I wasn't thinking about that, but sure, why not. A good answer is a good answer, regardless if it's on a dupe or not. That would work out rather well considering this will be merged before too long.

Comment: "F*&^ the community! I am in it for the rep!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically this already exists, the answer accepted by the original poster, and the answer accepted by the community (i.e. the one with the highest votes).

Answer (score 6):

Have more than one accepted-answer can be confusing.

If two or more answers are acceptable, they should probably be adapted into one single answer, and then that one should be accepted.

Comment: Possibly! I wouldn't know about the confusing aspect because the person who asked the question would know in most cases what worked for him and what didn't.

Comment: @Aeon: Confusing for those who have the same issue, and find your question. "Which of these do I implement..." If you coalesce the correct responses into one answer, and then accept that, there is no room for confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan: Agreed. Accepted answers are a scarce resource, if there is more than one correct answer, then these answerers should compete to make their response more complete, correct, or somehow better in order to earn the acceptance.  Everyone benefits from the extra effort on the part of answerers to make their response the best.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a nice comment saying:

> This is a good answer, too, but I can
>   only accept one.

...is just as good as getting that little check mark. Sometimes it even gets me a vote boost if other people think my answer should have been accepted. Bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason there is one accepted answer is to distill knowledge.  When other people use your question as a resource, they want to be immediately directed to the *one* most useful answer you received.  This is also why subjective questions are discouraged: ideally, there should be only one correct answer to a question.

Allowing multiple accepted answers dilutes the value of an accepted answer, and makes the format more forum-like than Q&A.

Comment: That's the reason for this feature request to distill the best from the better. I have received more than one excellent answer for a particular question and that too with bizzare frequency.